# Identify Required Frameworks for an app

Tags: macos, applications, bootable-disk

I'm trying to make a disk image as small as possible with a few apps on it.  I need to find out what framework packages each app uses so I can copy them onto the disk image in order for them to launch.  How do I find this information?

Using the console, I've noticed that some apps generate error messages with the Framework name, but others do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
otool -L /path/to/yourapp.app/Contents/MacOS/yourapp
```

This returns a list of the frameworks that the app binary makes reference to. They are listed with the path to the framework which lets you find the binary for copying, or you can write a script to parse the output to do this for you.

Make sure you run this command on the app binary, not the bundle.

Framework paths beginning with ‘@rpath’, ‘@executable_path’ or ‘@loader_path’ are frameworks located within the app bundle, so as long as you're copying the app bundle you don't have to do anything special with these frameworks.